# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#6>' to 'decimal'

Tags: c#, linq

hallo i have a linq query like this :

```
var data = from d in db.DailyBonus
                   where d.Date>= startDate1 && d.Date<=endDate1
                   group d by new { Em = d.Employee.Id } into g
                   select new BasisViewModel
                   {
                       EmployeeId = g.Key.Em,
                       EmployeeNumber = g.FirstOrDefault().Employee.EmployeeNumber,
                       FullName = g.FirstOrDefault().Employee.FullName,
                       HK1 = (decimal)g.FirstOrDefault().ManDays,
                       Basis1 = (decimal)g.FirstOrDefault().BonusBase,
                       HK2 = (
                              (from d in db.DailyBonus 
                              where d.Date>= startDate2 && d.Date<=endDate2
                              group d by new { Em = d.Employee.Id } into g2
                              select new 
                              {
                                 Mandays =  g.FirstOrDefault().ManDays <-- this is decimal type
                              }
                             ),
                   };
```

the problem is , i just want to select one record for `HK2` and assigned to Mandays in subquery but there is an error bellow :

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'decimal'

what is the solution ? thank you

Comment: What is the schema of HK2 ?

Comment: You need to be sure that `g.FirstOrDefault()` won't be null. If it can - then you'll get `NullReferenceException` one day :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of returning an *anonymous class* (`new {...}`)

```
  select new 
  {
       Mandays =  g.FirstOrDefault().ManDays <-- this is decimal type
  }
```

return a `Decimal` you want:

```
  select g.FirstOrDefault().ManDays;
```

Comment: Short and simple assuming HK2 is a decimal type, not a complex type

Comment: now the error changes to `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<decimal?>' to 'decimal'`

`from d in db.DailyBonus 
                                  where d.Date>= startDate2 && d.Date<=endDate2
                                  group d by new { Em = d.Employee.Id} into g2
                                  select g.FirstOrDefault().ManDays` like this?

Comment: @Mamen: it seems, that `HK2` is just a `Decimal`, so you have to take a single item from the whole query; i.e. `HK2 = (...).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

You should add another `FirstOrDefault()` in the end and use simple value instead of anonymous type:

```
var data = from d in db.DailyBonus
                       where d.Date>= startDate1 && d.Date<=endDate1
                       group d by new { Em = d.Employee.Id } into g
                       select new BasisViewModel
                       {
                           EmployeeId = g.Key.Em,
                           EmployeeNumber = g.FirstOrDefault().Employee.EmployeeNumber,
                           FullName = g.FirstOrDefault().Employee.FullName,
                           HK1 = (decimal)g.FirstOrDefault().ManDays,
                           Basis1 = (decimal)g.FirstOrDefault().BonusBase,
                           HK2 = (
                                  (from d in db.DailyBonus 
                                  where d.Date>= startDate2 && d.Date<=endDate2
                                  group d by new { Em = d.Employee.Id } into g2
                                  select g.FirstOrDefault().ManDays <-- this is simple value now

                                 ).FirstOrDefault(),<--this is another first or default 
                       };
```